Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/path/to/entry/file'
I have a VS Code extension which I want to bundle using Webpack.
// webpack.config.js:

'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const config = {
    target: 'webworker',
    entry: './src/extension.ts',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'extension.js',
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
        devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: '../[resource-path]'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    externals: {
        vscode: 'commonjs vscode'
    },
    resolve: {
        mainFields: ['browser', 'module', 'main'],
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    },
    stats: {
        errorDetails: true,
        children: true,
        logging: 'verbose'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'ts-loader',
                    options: {
                        compilerOptions: {
                            "module": "es6"
                        }
                    }
                }],
            }
        ]
    }
};
module.exports = config;

package.json script section is as follows:
"scripts": {
    "vscode:prepublish": "webpack --mode production",
    "webpack": "webpack --mode development",
    "webpack-dev": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "test-compile": "tsc -p ./"
},

When I try to build the project, it shows the following error:
ERROR in ../../../../../phxadenas101.oraclevcn.com/phx_wd202_db/WINDOWS.X64.rdd/240509/pack/src/extension.ts                                      
Module build failed (from ../../../../../moaadil/.ade/view_storage/moaadil_new_code9/odtvscode/src/client/oracle-vscode-extension/node_modules/ts-loader/index.js):                                                                          
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\ADE\phxadenas101.oraclevcn.com\phx_wd202_db\WINDOWS.X64.rdd\240509\pack\extension.ts'

The Error Logs are as follows:
LOG from webpack.Compiler
<t> make hook: 205.42232 ms
<t> finish make hook: 0.09599 ms
<t> finish compilation: 3.47329 ms
<t> seal compilation: 253.97149 ms
<t> afterCompile hook: 0.08616 ms

LOG from webpack.Compilation
<t> compute affected modules: 0.34445 ms
<t> finish modules: 2.39043 ms
<t> report dependency errors and warnings: 0.13842 ms
<t> optimize dependencies: 1.92586 ms
<t> create chunks: 3.60265 ms
<t> compute affected modules with chunk graph: 0.27417 ms
<t> optimize: 11.00395 ms
1 modules hashed, 0 from cache (1 variants per module in average)
<t> module hashing: 2.85093 ms
100% code generated (1 generated, 0 from cache)
<t> code generation: 2.7763 ms
<t> runtime requirements.modules: 0.21028 ms
<t> runtime requirements.chunks: 0.81756 ms
<t> runtime requirements.entries: 0.67766 ms
<t> runtime requirements: 2.35274 ms
<t> hashing: initialize hash: 0.01921 ms
<t> hashing: hash errors: 0.0134 ms
<t> hashing: sort chunks: 0.11652 ms
<t> hashing: hash runtime modules: 0.08556 ms
<t> hashing: hash chunks: 3.26823 ms
<t> hashing: hash digest: 0.09857 ms
<t> hashing: process full hash modules: 0.01031 ms
<t> hashing: 4.39249 ms
<t> module assets: 0.14279 ms
<t> create chunk assets: 4.06871 ms
<t> process assets: 218.9624 ms

LOG from webpack.FlagDependencyExportsPlugin
<t> restore cached provided exports: 0.70847 ms
<t> figure out provided exports: 0.02832 ms
0% of exports of modules have been determined (1 no declared exports, 0 not cached, 0 flagged uncacheable, 0 from cache, 0 from mem cache, 0 additional calculations due to dependencies)
<t> store provided exports into cache: 0.03432 ms

LOG from webpack.SideEffectsFlagPlugin
<t> update dependencies: 0.23559 ms

LOG from webpack.FlagDependencyUsagePlugin
<t> initialize exports usage: 0.0861 ms
<t> trace exports usage in graph: 0.70691 ms

LOG from webpack.buildChunkGraph
<t> visitModules: prepare: 0.27698 ms
<t> visitModules: visiting: 1.06934 ms
2 queue items processed (1 blocks)
0 chunk groups connected
0 chunk groups processed for merging (0 module sets, 0 forked, 0 + 0 modules forked, 0 + 0 modules merged into fork, 0 resulting modules)
0 chunk group info updated (0 already connected chunk groups reconnected)
<t> visitModules: 2.1249 ms
<t> connectChunkGroups: 0.10829 ms
<t> cleanup: 0.05732 ms

LOG from webpack.SplitChunksPlugin
<t> prepare: 0.04901 ms
<t> modules: 1.99088 ms
<t> queue: 0.01594 ms
<t> maxSize: 0.11632 ms

LOG from webpack.ModuleConcatenationPlugin
<t> select relevant modules: 0.24129 ms
<t> sort relevant modules: 0.01742 ms
<t> find modules to concatenate: 0.01966 ms
<t> sort concat configurations: 0.01326 ms
<t> create concatenated modules: 0.11737 ms
+ 3 hidden lines

LOG from webpack.FileSystemInfo
0 new snapshots created
0% root snapshot uncached (0 / 0)
0% children snapshot uncached (0 / 0)
0 entries tested
File info in cache: 0 timestamps 0 hashes 0 timestamp hash combinations
Directory info in cache: 0 timestamps 0 hashes 0 timestamp hash combinations
Managed items info in cache: 0 items

I am not sure how it is getting the path to extension.ts with all the rdd info. my project file is pack. My directory structure is a s follows:
.vscode
src
  - <other code files here>
  - extension.ts
dist
  - extension.js
package.json
webpack.config.js


Turns out it was looking for the path in a symlink.
Just adding symlinks: false to resolve fixed it.
resolve: {
     mainFields: ['browser', 'module', 'main'],
     extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
     symlinks: false,
},

